# Check ArrayList<String> contains("") method with equalsIgnoreCase

Tags: java, string, collections

I have an ArrayList();

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("aaa");
list.add("BBB");
list.add("cCc");
System.out.println(list.contains("aAa"));
```

Here i want to check contains() method with equalsIgnoreCase method in same line. 
How can i do it?

Comment: `List<String> list = new ArrayList();`, not possible it should be `List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();`

Comment: @PrasadKharkar: It is possible since JDK7...

Comment: @PrasadKharkar I believe `new ArrayList<>()` is also acceptable nowadays.

Comment: @Aquillo, Ohh... need to study jdk7 now. Can you please provide some good links for these differences?

Comment: @hexafraction, yeah couldn't know about the jdk7 changes. thanks for that

Comment: @PrasadKharkar: [Sure can...](http://google.com/)

Comment: @PrasadKharkar http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/enhancements.html#javase7

Comment: @Aquillo ... Got it :)

Comment: In JDK7, it is `new ArrayList<>();` (this is typed, and avoids redundancy by assuming same type as variable declaration `List<String> list = `) but it is **NOT** `new ArrayList();` (this is still untyped, it compiles with a warning)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
boolean containsEqualsIgnoreCase(Collection<String> c, String s) {
   for (String str : c) {
      if (s.equalsIgnoreCase(str)) {
          return true;
      }
   }
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't. The contract of `contains` is that it defers to `equals`. That's a fundamental part of the `Collection` interface. You have to write a custom method that iterates through the list and checks each value.

Answer (score 3):

This is an interesting question from an OO perspective.

One possibility is to transfer the responsibility of the contract you want to enforce (equality without case) to the collected elements themselves, not to the list, with respect to a proper separation of concern.

You would then add a new class for your String objects (without inheritance, `String` class is final) where you would implement your own hashCode/equals contract.

```
// Strictly speaking, this is not a String without case, since only
// hashCode/equals methods discard it. For instance, we would have 
// a toString() method which returns the underlying String with the 
// proper case.
public final class StringWithoutCase {
  private final String underlying;

  public StringWithoutCase(String underlying) {
    if (null == underlying)
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must provide a non null String");
    this.underlying = underlying;
  }

  // implement here either delegation of responsibility from StringWithoutCase
  // to String, or something like "getString()" otherwise.

  public int hashCode() {
    return underlying.toLowerCase().hashCode();
  }

  public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (! (other instanceof StringWithoutCase))
      return false;

    return underlying.equalsIgnoreCase(other.underlying);
  }
}
```

The objects populating the collection would be instances of `StringWithoutCase` :

```
Collection<StringWithoutCase> someCollection = ...
someCollection.add(new StringWithoutCase("aaa"));
someCollection.add(new StringWithoutCase("BBB"));
someCollection.add(new StringWithoutCase("cCc"));
```